# Como controlar o fluxo quando for digitado um valor inválido?

Tags: c

Caso eu queira que uma condição se repita várias e várias vezes tem como eu usar o comando `return` para alguma linha específica? Vou colocar o programa para explicar melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int aprovados, auxa=0, reprovados, auxr=0, notas=0, cont=0;

    while(cont<10)
    {
        printf("digite o resultado: ");
        scanf("%i", &notas);

        if(notas==1)
            auxa++;
        if(notas==2)
            auxr++;
        if(notas!=1 && notas!=2)
        {
            cont--;
            printf("esse valor nao eh valido digite 1 ou 2: ");
            scanf("%i", &notas);
            cont++;
            if(notas==1)
                auxa++;
            if(notas==2)
                auxr++;
        }

        cont++;
    }

    printf("aprovados:%i\n", auxa);
    printf("reprovados:%i\n", auxr);

    if(auxa>=8)
        printf("bonus ao instrutor\n");
    if(auxr>=7)
        printf("algo esta errado com o instrutor\n");

return 0;
}
```

Quero fazer o seguinte: no 3º `if` se eu digitar por exemplo 3 ele pede para digitar outro numero(eu sei que especifiquei no `printf` que é para digitar 1 ou 2) mas se eu digitar 3 logo em seguida o contador conta 1 incremento e se eu repetir números que não sejam 1 ou 2 (no caso fazer isso 20 vezes metade dessas vezes sera incrementado no contador) tem como eu dar um `return` para uma linha especifica toda vez que algum número diferente de 1 ou 2 seja digitado?

Comment: Está difícil entender a explicação. tente escrever de uma forma mais organizada, separe cada ideia. Isto até te ajuda entender o seu problema. Se o problema é difícil de entender em português ele será difícil de entender em C. Você sabe o que o `return` faz? Não me parece que você precisa dele no programa além de onde ele já está. Conhece o `continue`? Acho que é ele que você quer.

Comment: nossa tantas coisas que eu esqueci de marcar desculpa o atraso @bigown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu entendi, acho que é isto que deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int auxa = 0, auxr = 0, notas = 0, cont = 0;
    while (cont < 10) {
        printf("digite o resultado: ");
        scanf("%i", &notas);
        if (notas == 1)
            auxa++;
        if (notas == 2)
            auxr++;
        if (notas != 1 && notas != 2)
            continue;
        cont++;
    }
    printf("aprovados:%i\n", auxa);
    printf("reprovados:%i\n", auxr);
    if (auxa >= 8)
        printf("bonus ao instrutor\n");
    if (auxr >= 7)
        printf("algo esta errado com o instrutor\n");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/QmDO5c). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lldkxdyo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/AprovedReproved.c).

O programa tem outros problemas mas acho que responde sua pergunta. Além disto tem maneiras melhor de fazer o mesmo, mas acho melhor não tentar te ensinar o melhor estilo de código até que você entenda o que o código faz.

Answer (score 2):

O comando `Return` não faz isso que você está querendo, que seria "pular"/"retornar" para uma linha, semelhante a `jmp` em assembly. Você não consegue fazer isso em C. O `Return` finaliza certa função e retorna o seu valor para a saída da função.

Se eu entendi a sua questão, você está procurando o que o bigdown respondeu, utilizando o `Continue`

Comment: É hoje eu ja entendo XD mas obrigado pela dica eu sempre agradeço dessa vez eu tinha esquecido kkko